# How to delete a TODO item list from DOM when I click delete button using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, removechild, http-delete

In delete function of TODO item I want to delete a specific todo item with given id but I am having difficulty in selecting parent i.e. div tag in which I have stored the title description and delete button which I am adding by sending a request using JavaScript. Problem how to delete div tag of specific delete button having id using removeChild()? How to do that?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TODO app</title>
</head>
 <script>

    function deleteDone(id) {
        console.log("Deleted todo ID:", id);
        // Delete the right todo from the list
        // You will need to give each todo an id, and that should be enough to remove it
      

    }
    function deleteTodo(id) {
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/todos/" + id, {
            method: "DELETE",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }).then(deleteDone)
    }


    function getTodoscallBack(data){
        console.log(data);
        var parentElement = document.getElementById("mainArea");
        // parentElement.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;++i){
            var childElement = document.createElement("div");

            var grandChildren1 = document.createElement("span");
            grandChildren1.innerHTML= data[i].title;
            var grandChildren2 = document.createElement("span");
            grandChildren2.innerHTML= data[i].description;
            var grandChildren3 = document.createElement("button");
            grandChildren3.innerHTML="Delete";
            grandChildren3.setAttribute("onclick","deleteTodo("+data[i].id+")");
            
            childElement.appendChild(grandChildren1);
            childElement.appendChild(grandChildren2);
            childElement.appendChild(grandChildren3);
            
            parentElement.appendChild(childElement);

        }
        
    }
    function callbackFn2(res){
        res.json().then(getTodoscallBack);
    }
    function getData(){
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/todos",{
            method:"GET",
        }).then(callbackFn2);
            
    }

    getData();
    function parsedResponse(data){
        console.log(data);
        var parentElement = document.getElementById("mainArea");
        var childElement = document.createElement("div");

            var grandChildren1 = document.createElement("span");
            grandChildren1.innerHTML= data.title;
            var grandChildren2 = document.createElement("span");
            grandChildren2.innerHTML= data.description;
            var grandChildren3 = document.createElement("button");
            grandChildren3.innerHTML="Delete";
            
            childElement.appendChild(grandChildren1);
            childElement.appendChild(grandChildren2);
            childElement.appendChild(grandChildren3);
            
            parentElement.appendChild(childElement);
    }
    function callback(res){
        res.json().then(parsedResponse);
    }
  
      function onPress(){
        var  title = document.getElementById("title").value;
        var  description = document.getElementById("description").value;
        
        console.log(title,"\n",description);

        fetch("http://localhost:3000/todos",{
            method:"POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                title: title,
                description:description
            }),
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }).then(callback);
    }


 </script>
<body>
    
    Todo title
    <input type="text" id="title"></input>
    <br><br>
    Todo description
    <input type="text" id="description"></input>
    <br><br>
    <button onclick="onPress()">send todo</button>
    <div id="mainArea">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when you click on a target that triggers the corresponding click event, you are supposed to have the related `Event` object holding the element triggering such event. In general for traversing the dom, you can use [closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to retrieve the first parent element matching the given selector.

Comment: so in deeper terms you should better understand the events in javascript.. but to cut it short, you may just add the keyword `this` as the argument of a function you are calling inside the inline event handler.. like `<button onclick="deleteTodo(this);">delete</button>`  and the js `function deleteTodo(target){ target.closest('div.todocontainer').remove();}`

Comment: But I am passing id  see :   function deleteDone(id) {
        console.log("Deleted todo ID:", id);
        // Delete the right todo from the list
        // You will need to give each todo an id, and that should be enough to remove it
      

    }
    function deleteTodo(id) {
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/todos/" + id, {
            method: "DELETE",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }).then(deleteDone)
    }  just made the changes in it?

Comment: You can and probably should use another means of selection rather than ID attributes which are diccicult to work with if you have potentially hundreds of these bits of HTML. As @DiegoD suggested, use the `event` property of the `click` to access the `event.target` and from there use parent/child/sibling type selectors to access nodes of interest. Any ID  used can be assigned to a parent/container and should be the ID in the db if you are storing/deleting from a db

Comment: #079_RISHABH I didn't go that far.. when reading _I want to delete a specific todo item_ I supposed you meant to delete an element from DOM. What you highlighted now is a totally different matter..it's calling an api passing an id that will be needed to match such item on a DB. I don't know anymore what's the question I'm expected to answer

Comment: fyi: there is no `</input>` tag

Comment: I agree that using an id for the sake of fetching the corresponding element is overkill.. because the delete button could show up several times in the same page. Despite you still need to keep track of those items on the backend, that id should still believe to the container and not to the delete button. The delete button click event should just, in general, retrieve the element triggering the event and do its logic related to the `closest` container holding the item id

Comment: I eventually added an answer... anyway I must say that if you included the object in your code by yourself, things went much quicker.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your same exact code and passed a bogus array modeling the todo as you did already

```
const todos = [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'title#1',
    description: 'description#1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'title#2',
    description: 'description#2'   
  }];
```

To remain consistent with your strategy, in your logic creating the todo items, I added the feature of setting the `data-id` attribute of each delete button with the corresponding todo id, and then inside the `deleteDone` function I fetched the clicked delete button using an attribute selector and later removed the whole `div` container retrieved using `closest`.

```js
const todos = [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'title#1',
    description: 'description#1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'title#2',
    description: 'description#2'   
  }];

getTodoscallBack(todos);


function deleteDone(id) {
  console.log("Deleted todo ID:", id);

  //retrieves the delete button holding the data-id attribute passed
  const delButton = document.querySelector(`[data-id="${id}"`);
  //retrieves the element containing that button
  const todoContainer = delButton.closest('div');
  //removes the whole div containing the todo
  todoContainer.remove();

}

function deleteTodo(id) {
  /*
  fetch("http://localhost:3000/todos/" + id, {
    method: "DELETE",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  }).then(deleteDone)
  */
  deleteDone(id);
}


function getTodoscallBack(data) {
  console.log(data);
  var parentElement = document.getElementById("mainArea");
  // parentElement.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var childElement = document.createElement("div");

    var grandChildren1 = document.createElement("span");
    grandChildren1.innerHTML = data[i].title;
    var grandChildren2 = document.createElement("span");
    grandChildren2.innerHTML = data[i].description;
    var grandChildren3 = document.createElement("button");
    grandChildren3.innerHTML = "Delete";
    grandChildren3.setAttribute("onclick", "deleteTodo(" + data[i].id + ")");

    //HERE I set the data-id attribute value as data[i].id
    grandChildren2.dataset.id = data[i].id;

    childElement.appendChild(grandChildren1);
    childElement.appendChild(grandChildren2);
    childElement.appendChild(grandChildren3);

    parentElement.appendChild(childElement);

  }

}

function callbackFn2(res) {
  res.json().then(getTodoscallBack);
}

function getData() {
  fetch("http://localhost:3000/todos", {
    method: "GET",
  }).then(callbackFn2);

}

getData();

function parsedResponse(data) {
  console.log(data);
  var parentElement = document.getElementById("mainArea");
  var childElement = document.createElement("div");

  var grandChildren1 = document.createElement("span");
  grandChildren1.innerHTML = data.title;
  var grandChildren2 = document.createElement("span");
  grandChildren2.innerHTML = data.description;
  var grandChildren3 = document.createElement("button");
  grandChildren3.innerHTML = "Delete";

  childElement.appendChild(grandChildren1);
  childElement.appendChild(grandChildren2);
  childElement.appendChild(grandChildren3);

  parentElement.appendChild(childElement);
}

function callback(res) {
  res.json().then(parsedResponse);
}

function onPress() {
  var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
  var description = document.getElementById("description").value;

  console.log(title, "\n", description);

  fetch("http://localhost:3000/todos", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
      title: title,
      description: description
    }),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  }).then(callback);
}
```

```html
<body>

  Todo title
  <input type="text" id="title">
  <br><br> Todo description
  <input type="text" id="description">
  <br><br>
  <button onclick="onPress()">send todo</button>
  <div id="mainArea">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Diego for your help but I think I coudn't resolve the issue.

Comment: _I think_ and _couldn't resolve the issue_ aren't deep enough to understand what you are talking about. This demo shows how to encode the id of each todo inside each delete button so that when you click on it, the button knows everything it needs to perform its action. Indeed when you click on a delete button you can see the correspondent todo is removed. Now the only trick I did there was commenting the actual `fetch`statement and called `deleteDone(id);` directly. Is that the issue you encountered? plugging that logic with your own fetch?